Problem with making a .jar with JavaFX and maven
newbie here, I´m creating an App in IntelliJ with Maven, JDK 22, non-modular and using JavaFX 17.0.10, the problem is that when I generate my .jar with dependencies, it doesn't open by double clicking it, instead I have to use java --module-path "C:\path\to\javafx-sdk-17.0.10\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar BO-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar  in cmd.
When i run mvn clean package I recieve this error:
[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:17.0.10 [WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:17.0.10 [WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:jar:17.0.10 [WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:jar:17.0.10 [WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:17.0.10 [WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:17.0.10 [WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:17.0.10 [WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:17.0.10
I need this app to be runned by double clicking it because i need to use it in multiple devices.
Here is my pom.xml:
`
4.0.0
<groupId>com.BO</groupId>
<artifactId>BO</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    <itext.version>8.0.5</itext.version>
    <javafx.version>17.0.10</javafx.version> <!-- Usa la versión más reciente -->
    <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-repo-itext</id>
        <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>openjfx</id>
        <url>https://openjfx.io/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.4.1.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>22</source>
                <target>22</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


`

if it doesn't start with double clicking, the problem might also be an external one, in the configuration of your environment_variables of your os

The app open, but it shows me an "A Java Exception error has ocurred"

so it does start by double clicking. Keep in mind, the stacktrace you are showing is a warning, not an error. Though warnings shouldn't be ignored, they won't crash your application

I would strongly advise you to change the default 'open' command for jars from javaw.exe to java.exe (if you haven't already) then you won't run into the problem of missing important error information. Keep in mind, the stacktrace you are showing is a warning, not an error. Let's keep this clear, what is being shown is Maven logging output, which is indeed a warning. What is being talked about, however, is an exception, which is quite a different thing, evidently 'fatal'

I don't think you did the necessary reading of the documentation yet. I.E. : https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/modular . JavaFX is not just like any other Java application, it requires special steps to distribute such applications in a moderately useable way. I would strongly consider packaging a minimal JRE with the application for example, so target machines do not need a Java runtime installed. Also documented in the given link.

@Gimby, certainly I think a modular approach is probably safer, but as against that, is it possible to treat the assembly as an app with jars? I'm not sure

@g00se It's possible, but unsupported and not guaranteed to work in future versions. Basically, you have to bundle the JavaFX libraries in the jar (note this means you need a different jar for each platform), and that involved loading the JavaFX classes from the classpath instead of the module path. See this answer. There is a lot of discussion about this on the tag wiki.

All very interesting thanks. So David, to distribute/deploy your app painlessly, you really should modularise it

How could I modularise it? I'm a bit lost
